# NSURLConnection does not call delegate connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am trying to detect an http response code of 302. This is my request line:

```
urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:response] retain];
```

The `response` variable is an instance of a class I created which implements:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)inConnection: 
             willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest 
            redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse 
{
    NSLog(@"redirect");
    return inRequest;
}
```

But for some reason this is not being hit. I'm 100% sure the service call is being hit and is returning a 302. Is there something else I am missing not written in the documentation in order to get this delegate called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra colon:

```
 ...(NSURLConnection *)inConnection: willSend...
```

Remove that and you should be good to go.

(Remember, colons are part of method names; you have to get them exactly right!)

Comment: This is what I get for not coding in Objective-c for so long. My eyes did not pick up on that at all. Thank you!